# IIS Web Server and web.config: Rewritten URL is displayed in Browser

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, web-config

I use the following rule within a web server configuration file (web.config, IIS Web Server).

The purpose of the rule is to add a new folder to the URL path.
The new folder shouldn't be visible in the browser's address bar.

The rule works fine, but the rewritten URL ([www.domain.com/newfolder/...](http://www.domain.com/newfolder/...)) is displayed in the browser's address bar.
I thought a rewritten URL is only processed by the web server and not by the browser client? What can I do, so that "newfolder" is not visible in the browser?

I don't want to use a 'redirect rule' but a 'rewrite rule'.

'''

```
    <rewrite>
                    
        <rules>

            <rule name="New folder" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^(.*)$" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/newfolder" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="/newfolder/{R:0}" appendQueryString="true" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
            </rule>

        </rules>
            
    </rewrite>
```

'''

Comment: You made an assumption that only IIS URL Rewrite module can issue 30x redirection responses and change the browser address bar, but sadly that's not very true. Besides, your browser might cache previous redirection responses for its own reasons. So, 1) use a privacy tab for testing. 2) Identify where the 30x responses come from (browser developer tools as well as IIS failed request tracing).

Comment: A rewrite is a server-side rewrite of the URL before it’s fully processed by IIS. This does not change the URL in the browser address bar because the changes are hidden from the user. I didn't quite understand your description, do you want to hide newfolder in the browser address bar through rewriting rules? For example: If your original URL is www.domain.com/newfolder/abc... Do you want to visit the webpage by entering www.domain.com/abc... in the address bar of your browser?

Comment: @YurongDai: Thank you for your response. Yes, you're right, I am trying to hide 'newfolder'. But unfortunately it is visible in the browser address bar.

Comment: I think your requirement cannot be achieved by rewrite rules, you need to use redirect rules. Even if you don't want to use it, it's a valid workaround. https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/iis-support-blog/remove-folder-application-names-from-urls/ba-p/2385204